# Why does my dog continues to urinate even after he puts his leg down

Tags: dogs, health

For the past few weeks while walking my dog, after he urinates and puts his leg down, pee continues to come out of him.

We had his urine test done and everything was fine. I'm wondering what is wrong with him.

Comment: What did the vet say when you tested the urine?

Comment: That it was normal. Nothing found.  No infection, even had them check sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than this being a urinary tract issue, it is possible that the issue may be orthopedic - maybe he’s experiencing pain or discomfort when he lifts his leg and he puts it down, sooner than he used to. Your veterinarian can palpate and manipulate your dog’s back, hips and knees - in an attempt to determine if there’s any discomfort, and advise you, accordingly.

Comment: This answer does not seem to add much, the OP indicates they have already seen the vet, this might be better as a comment asking if the vet checked for these issues.  If the OP answers no, then an expanded answer around  orthopedic with good references would be appropriate.

Comment: @JamesJenkins Thanks for the comment. I am new, here and at the time of my posting, I did not have sufficient points to add a comment. Now that I am able to comment, yes... It would be interesting to learn if the vet had explored ortho issues. From what was written, we just don't know much about the vet as a diagnostician.

Comment: I find this answer just okay. "Urine test done" does not indicate a more thorough veterinary examination. Maybe it is not the best of answers, but at least it still remains the only answer after two months gone by since the question was posted. I gave it an upvote.